# Getting error in C++ code (vector implementation)

Tags: c++

I am writing C++ code where I am using an array of vector in the form :

```
vector<int> s1[k];
```

In some compiler, I am not getting any error but in some compiler, I am getting error:

> Compile time error (error: ISO C++ forbids variable-size array 's1'
>   compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.)

I don't understand why it's behaving differently in different compilers and how do I fix this problem?

Comment: some compilers allow non-standard variable-size arrays, some dont. Why do you need a c-style array of vectors anyhow?

Comment: VLA's aren't supported by the c++ standard.

Answer (score 1):

Your `k` is probably not constant. C++ doesn't allow variable length arrays like C does.

Use 
`std::vector<std::vector<int>> s1(k)` instead, if it is supposed to be dynamic array.

Comment: @pharask Then it's not constant :P

Comment: @pharask We don't see `const int k` declared anywhere, and asking users for input is *definitely not* constant.

Comment: @pharask Think twice thouroughly about your statement. How can k be constant if user inputs it?